# jQuery UI: Date Picker trouble?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have made a cool skin for my date picker. For some reason when you click run, there is a black bar underneath, but when you click on the input, and click on the page, it is gone. Can i get rid of the black bar? http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/WMptu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/bibin_v/WMptu/1/

Comment: is there any way to make the header smaller?

Comment: For that you will have to change `ui-widget` font-size. I think that is specified for whole widget.

Comment: when i did that, it made the whole thing smaller and biger, i just need the header smaller

Comment: add 
`.ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}`

at the end of style it will work

Comment: OK, i need the header background to be smaller, not the text.